# How to solve $y'' + y = -2\sin(x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I don't know how to find the particular solution of  $$y'' +  y = -2\sin(x)$$

I started with $$y'' +  y = 0$$ to find the homogeneous form $$A\cos(x)+B\sin(x)$$

But now i am stuck.

Comment: Have you heard of the method of [undetermined coefficients](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx)?

Comment: $$f(x) = -2sin(x)$$ has the form of $$Csin(x)$$?

Comment: You also have the Wronksian method if you like to memorize formulas.

Comment: I pick your suggested particular and differentiate it twice and substitute it in the original equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find the particular solution.

Let $y_{p}=x(a\cos x+b\sin x)$.

\begin{align*}
  y'_{p} &= a\cos x+b\sin x+x(-a\sin x+b\cos x) \\
  y''_{p} &= 2(-a\sin x+b\cos x)-x(a\cos x+b\sin x) \\
  y''_{p}+y_{p} &= 2(-a\sin x+b\cos x) \\
  -2\sin x &= 2(-a\sin x+b\cos x) \\
  (a,b) &= (1,0) \\
  y(x) &= A\cos x+B\sin x+x\cos x
\end{align*}

> **Further points to be noticed**
>
> Note that $-2\sin x$ is one of the possibilities of the general solution $A\cos x+B\sin x$, the form $y_{p}=a\cos x+b\sin x$ always makes the LHS of the ODE to be zero. It's simpler to try the form of $x(a\cos x+b\sin x)$ and we found that it's doable.  It's in fact a resonance term.

Comment: I want to emphasize the needed $x$ upfront the $(acosx+bsinx)$. Is it clear to the OP why that $x$ sits there??

Comment: @imranfat Thanks for your suggestion, further notes have been appended.

Comment: @imranfat yes, because the homogeneous part includes the solution $Acosx + Bsinx $ already